# Where to find strings for $Resources:core

Tags: resource-files

I want to find out what string lies under `$Resources:core,...`.

Is there a list, or a class where I can see what exactly are the values for those resources?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, take a look into the file

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\core.resx

The format is :

> $Resources:**name_of_resource_file**, **key_of_ressource**

A warning thought, this will concerns the resources you will find in all xml files, or in code.

In aspx markup, the resources will be read from

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\Resources

These files, plus some resources files taken from features, will be duplicated into

> c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\yourapp\App_GlobalResources

Comment: The 14 folder contains a lot of useful things. Hard to find sometimes, but very useful to understand some behaviors of SharePoint. Do not hesitate to to look into this folder !